# TypeError: _react2.default.PropTypes is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I recently upgraded my project to use React 16.4.1 instead of 15.2.1.
I had the following component which broke by giving me the TypeError: _react2.default.PropTypes is undefined error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object,
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/login');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/login');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

I changed the code to the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/login');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/login');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  Authentication.propTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

but now I get TypeError: this.context.router is undefined. Can someone explain me or point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you changed `contextTypes` to `propTypes` in your second snippet.

Comment: Just changed the code again but I am still getting the same error. Can you expand more on your comment?

Comment: @AlessandroCali prop types has been moved to a seperate project in react 16. if you are relying on it heavily, you will have install it with `npm install prop-types` and then import it like `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` and use it as needed. see here for more info -> https://reactjs.org/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html

Comment: @r3wt, yes, I have done the following. I've had this broken code for a while now and today I touched it again with the intention to fix it once for all. I'm obviously stuck somewhere and don't know exactly where. Was hoping someone who already did this could help me figure my problem out

Comment: Did you upgrade your version of react-router as well? I suggest using their `withRouter` higher-order component rather than try to use `this.context.router`: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Ross Allen's comment I ended up using withRouter.
The code that I currently have is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      router: PropTypes.object
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        const {router} = this.props;
        router.push('/login');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        const {router} = this.props;
        router.push('/login');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
  }

  return withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication));
}
```

It works, maybe there could be more enhancements.

Answer (score -1):

as of react 15.5, the PropTypes library is in its own package, `prop-types`.

solution:

1.install prop-types package in your project:

```
npm i prop-types --save
```

2.import it as necessary and use it

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Please note, this also means you will probably have to upgrade any libraries relying on PropTypes to their post react 15.5 versions. in some cases, some libraries may not have upgrades available, so you will need to open pull requests. so now you are armed with all the information you need to fix this problem. It won't be easy but if you want react 16's features, its well worth it. I did the upgrade and it took me about 2 or 3 hours to get everything working.

read more here:
https://reactjs.org/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html

Comment: So, I have tried a few things around. All unsuccessful. I have updated my question to the most recent code that I have but I am still confused. Since you have already been through this, how would you change my original code so that it is complaint with React 16?